# Backbone collection.'at(index)' is returning multiple items

Tags: javascript, css, backbone.js

I have a problem related with iteration of functions in Backbone.

```
    //View
    var PanelView = BlockView.extend({ 
        //BACKBONE PROPERTIES AND FUNCTIONS 
            className   : 'panel', 
            initialize  : function(){ 
                            BlockView.prototype.initialize.call(this);
                         }, 
            //RENDERING FUNCTIONS FOR THINGS WITH COLLECTIONS
            render      : function(){ 
                            //check special properties 
                            this.$el.css(this.model.get('css')); 
                            this.renderType(); 
                            //render data from the blocks 
                            if(this.model.get('collection')){
                                this.model.get('collection').each(this.renderBlock, this);
                            }else{
                                this.renderBlock(this.model.get('block')); 
                            }
                            //return to the dialog 
                            return this; 
                         }, 
            renderBlock : function(block){
                            var view = block.get('view'); 
                            var blockView = new view({model:block}); 
                            this.$el.append(blockView.render().el); 
                          },
            renderType : function(){
                            //if there is a collection, change the css of the blocks according to the display type of the panel. 
                            if(this.model.get('collection')){ 
                                alert('rendering type');
                                switch(this.model.get('display').type){
                                    case 'rows':    
                                        //change css of blocks to be in rows 
                                        this.model.setRows();           
                                        break; 
                                    case 'columns':
                                        this.model.setColumns(); 
                                        break;
                                    case 'grid':
                                        this.model.setGrid();  
                                };                                          
                            }                           
                          }         
    }); //View 

//Model function
    setColumns  : function(){
                    if(this.get('collection')){                 
                        var block = this.get('collection').at(0); 
                        block.get('css').width = 500 + '%'; 
                        console.log(this.get('collection').at(0)); 
                    }
    },
```

This seems pretty simple and so far this or each.

Each functions were working fine until I got to this specific problem. For some reason this is changing the css values of multiple blocks even though it should not.

This function is NOT being called multiple times, it only happens once. Even when I check out the variable in the console it returns one block in the collection.

Can anyone help me identify why this specific piece of code would be iterating over multiple objects?

I would attach all of the code but its multiple pages long. This is the only piece of code that seems to be functioning strangely. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem is that

```
block.get('css').width = 500 + '%';
```

Is actually modifying the Block prototype. Each of the types of blocks extends Block, along with its base CSS. Since they don't have their own CSS they simply use the prototype css object. changing block.get('css').width calls that and changes that property, hence all of the blocks.

I fixed it by using block.set(css:{width: 500 + '%'}) which sets it on that specific block.

Now I know why set is necessary :D

Answer (score 0):

do not pass this as parameter in the each function call

```
    .each(this.renderBlock, this);
```

what you are sending is not the item but the context. I think if you pass item should work fine.

```
    .each(this.renderBlock, item, this);
```

Comment: That's not true. That .each() function needs the 'this' as the last parameter so that the renderBlock function can effectively call 'this.$el' from the proper context. Multiple objects call that function (even objects that are not panels).

Comment: you are right I think then the part missing is the item. like the second line